# Sort column in new data

Tags: r

In R I have `data`

```
Name   Number
Peter   51
Phil    12
...
```

I want to create a new data- set where the `number` are sorted. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `order` function

```
mydata[order(Number),]
```

Try below

```
name<-c('peter','phil')
number<-c(51,12)
mydata<-data.frame(name,number)
mydata[order(number),]
```

Output :

```
   name number
2  phil     12
1 peter     51
```